# How to export a Flash Catalyst Component into a swc file

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flashcatalyst

I want to exported designed components from Flash Catalyst to IDEA.

Because FXPL is a specific adobe format, i need it in a little bit more generic format like an swc.

So how is the best way to get my component into an swc ?

I found a lot of scripts / hacks to pack actionsscript / flex assets into an swc but i would like to have an "official" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Flash builder, right click and say "new Flex Library Project"
2. In the options screen that shows up, select "Make project Flash Catalyst Compatible"
3. Now go to Project -> Flash Catalyst -> Import Flash Catalyst Project
4. Select "import contents into existing project", select a package
5. Build project (should happen automatically) and in the bin folder is your SWC.

Comment: I figured out the same a few minutes ago. 

Its ok but i hope they improve somehow the process.... But maybe the try to bind the developers to FC + FB combinations

Comment: I've never done it, but apparently if you check that "make project flash catalyst compatible" you should be able to do "round tripping" with Catalyst. I'm not sure of the details but CS5.5 and FB4.5 states this as a feature. Would that make things easier?

Comment: The Roundtrip works but only with some restrictions.  If you start with a comptible project for example, it will work until you import external libs in your fxp ;) like fxpls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure the FXP file that catalyst creates is just a normal zip file with a custom extension.  Just change the extension to zip and you can extract all of it's content into your project.

I also found [this post](http://www.rogue-development.com/blog2/2009/06/compiling-fxp-swc-a-catalyst-workflow/) that has a ruby script that extracts the fxp and compiles it into a swc which might be useful for you, but really you could do this with any language, or even use ANT to do it automatically.

Comment: I also found the ruby script. But its more a hack than a solution to use in the workflow of several designers / devolpers, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, which is why you should just create a simple ANT script that can be run by the developers in IntelliJ.  It's a simple zip extract and mxmlc compilation :)

Comment: We have to see if we will use Catalyst at all. Looks still to be a beta to me. ;) And in the meantime i will do the roundtrip with FB